# Is there a way to get the dates of the week for the month?

Tags: javascript, asp-classic

So the only value that I have is the month. For example this february how will I know that the days for the 1st week is 1, the second week is 2 - 8 and so on.

I'm using this for a report generation and there should be a weekly report also. May be you can give me another way of pulling of this reports.

I'm using classic asp and javascript for this system.

Comment: Are you wanting a [tag:Javascript] or a [tag:asp-classic] solution?

Answer (score 0):

The library [Moment.js](http://momentjs.com) will help you with this.

Get the number of days in the month.

```
moment("2012-02", "YYYY-MM").daysInMonth() // 29
moment("2012-01", "YYYY-MM").daysInMonth() // 31
```

(http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/days-in-month)

This method can be used to set the day of the week, with Sunday as 0 and Saturday as 6:

```
moment().day(Number|String);
moment().day(); // Number
moment().days(Number|String);
moment().days(); // Number
```

(http://momentjs.com/docs/#/get-set/day/)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a well used [asp-classic](/questions/tagged/asp-classic) solution that's been around for a while.

```vb
<%
' Copyright (c) 2008, reusablecode.blogspot.com; some rights reserved.
'
' This work is licensed under the Creative Commons Attribution License. To view
' a copy of this license, visit http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/3.0/ or
' send a letter to Creative Commons, 559 Nathan Abbott Way, Stanford, California
' 94305, USA.

' Check if a year is a leap year.
function isLeapYear(someYear)
    if someYear Mod 4 = 0 and (someYear Mod 100 <> 0 or (someYear Mod 100 = 0 and someYear Mod 400 = 0)) then
        isLeapYear = True
    else
        isLeapYear = False
    end if
end function

' Returns the number of days in a given month (and in the case of February, for the given year).
' REQUIRES: isLeapYear()
function MonthDays(someMonth, someYear)
    select case someMonth
    case 1, 3, 5, 7, 8, 10, 12
        MonthDays = 31
    case 4, 6, 9, 11
        MonthDays = 30
    case 2
        if isLeapYear(someYear) then
            MonthDays = 29
        else
            MonthDays = 28
        end if
    end select
end function
%>
```

To use it

```vb
<%
Dim daysinmonth
'Number if days in January 2014
daysinmonth = MonthDays(1, 2014)
%>
```